# How to convert csv file into geo database file?

Tags: c#, file-geodatabase, csv, ogr2ogr

I have a csv file that i want to export to a file geodatabase (*.gdb) in C#.

I am currently looking into GDAL ogr2ogr commands.

They have a way to [convert gdb file into csv file](https://nygeog.github.io//2014/file/geodatabase/shapefile/osgeo4w/2014/08/28/filegeodatabase_osgeo4w_ogr.html) but not the opposite.

Is there a way using GDAL or ogr2ogr to export csv to gdb file?

What i really want to do is that my database table's data is already exported into separate csv files and i want to write that data from csv files to FileGDB and export it (the entire directory as a zip). GDAL ogr2ogr has commands to export FileGDB into csv or several formats but not the opposite. So if i have a ogr2ogr command or a way to do that all i will do is run the cmd command from c# code.

I know how to run the command from a code, all i need is a **command** to export csv to FileGDB. (it doesn't have to be a command, it can be a external driver or tool or configuration or a method to do that)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: You've got several different topics in this question. If you want coding assistance you need to provide your code, along with a clear description of what isn't working. I will point out that a file geodatabase is a ***container***, so asking to convert a CSV to a "file geodatabase" is like trying to convert a text file to a directory folder. Instead,  you want to create a table ***in*** an FGDB.

Comment: Thanks @vice for pointing out that .gdb is container containing lots of files. I have come to know that a little while after asking the question. I already have a table data exported in csv file. I need to convert this into gdb table.